# how to implement month,day,week view calendar in salesforce

Tags: community

how to implement month,day,week view calendar in sales-force like Google calendar

i have to implement this requirement by using visual-force page

when i click on the particular day i have to open a pop window there we have to enter event name and time

Comment: have you tried writing any code to start this ? you wont get complete code answers here. you can start googling to see if there are existing libraries or appexchange apps matching your requirement..

Answer (score 1):

Use this (http://fullcalendar.io/) it is awesome. Multiple view types and can drag/drop events if necessary.

Comment: Thaank you....................i want to customize this calendar how can i do that one i want to display the events with different colors based upon record type

Comment: Have a look at http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/ and see the backgroundColor attribute. Pass the color in via the JSON representation of the event.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Chatter Calender https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IyFMEA0.  Might cover most of your requirements and you have access to the code so you can change as required.